# Make Haskell List Recursion function more efficient

Tags: list, haskell, recursion, boolean, pattern-matching

I've written a function that will compare two lists and check to see if the first is a prefix of the second and it must be done using recursion.

For example:

```
prefix [1,2] [1,2,3]
>True
prefix [2,1,4] [2,1,13,4]
>False
```

Now I've done this but I feel it's inefficient:

```
prefix :: [Int] -> [Int] -> Bool
prefix (x:xs) (y:ys)
|   null xs                         =   True
|   x == y && head xs == head ys    =   True && prefix xs ys
|   head xs /= head ys              =   False
```

I was hoping it could be done more efficiently and with some better pattern matching. Can it be?

Comment: A good way to catch missing patterns is to run GHC with `-fwarn-incomplete-patterns` or just `-Wall`. Typically, write `{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall #-}` way up at the top of the file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to use the `head` function at all. That doubles the number of comparisons. Try this:

```haskell
prefix :: [Int] -> [Int] -> Bool
prefix [] _ = True
prefix _ [] = False
prefix (x:xs) (y:ys)
  | x == y = prefix xs ys
  | otherwise = False
```

Comment: Oh I see, yes that does work and I've now found an instance in which mine doesn't, when I make the first list contain any single integer it will return true. Can you explain the `(_:_)` part of your solution?

Comment: `(_:_) []` matches the case when the first list is longer than the second, meaning the first could never be a prefix of the second. (the code could actually be shortened to `_ []` since we've already matched on an empty first list in the first pattern)

Comment: @GarethAllen-Stringer `(x:xs)` in that case pattern-matches on the first item of the list (`x`) and the tail (`xs`), see http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions

Answer (score 2):

Chad Gilbert's solution can be streamlined very slightly:

```
prefix :: [Int] -> [Int] -> Bool
prefix [] _ = True
prefix (x:xs) (y:ys)
  | x == y = prefix xs ys
prefix _ _ = False
```

This won't affect the performance, but it demonstrates a language feature: when all the guards on a pattern fail, that match will be abandoned and matching will resume with the next pattern.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Prelude > let prefix [] _ = True
 Prelude |     prefix _ [] = False
 Prelude |     prefix (x:xs) (y:ys) = if ( x==y) then prefix xs ys else False
```

Examples:

```
  Prelude> prefix [1,3] []
  False
  Prelude> prefix [] [1,2,3]
  True
  Prelude> prefix [1,2] [1,2,3]
  True
```